# php c extension: list of api functions available?

Tags: php, php-extension

maybe this is something I've not understood well, but I'm wondering why there is no clearly defined list of functions that you can call when writing php extensions in C.

There doesn't appear to be a list of functions, such as php_printf() or zend_parse_arguments.  Just a rag tag collection of websites explaining this or that.

I'm looking for a complete list of functions, that I'm allowed to call from inside my C extension, a reference manual, or at least, some form of documentation

I apologise if this question is super easy and I've overlooked something, but if you know where I can find this list, then I'd be very happy to hear it!

Comment: The only complete list of functions is the source itself ;)

Comment: While Sara's Book is rather out of date now, and doesn't contain a comprehensive list, it's still the best source of information available for writing PHP Extensions

Comment: wow....a book from 2006 and the source code are the only help, hmm, ok, I'll go look on google books ;) maybe you should put saras book as your answer? seems like the right one, unless somebody has a better one